# Websockets Sec-WebSocket-Accept invalid in Vala

Tags: html, websocket, vala

I have got to the point where I have no where else to search and been at this for 2 days.

I am trying to implement server side for Websockets in Vala. I have been following the RFC [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) as well as tried to convert examples from other languages.

```
string res = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + "\r\n"
            + "Connection: Upgrade" + "\r\n"
            + "Upgrade: websocket" + "\r\n"
            + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + Base64.encode(Checksum.compute_for_string(ChecksumType.SHA1,
                Regex.split_simple("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)", request)[1].strip() + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
            ).data;)
            + "\r\n\r\n";
```

The output from my Vala code is different from both C# and PHP outputs. The key sent to my browser is:

```
y/WXsXKM98if/+AUaqF6iQ==
```

PHP and C# give me the following result:

```
ZGZhMTEyNjkxNDBkNGQ4YzlmOGFmNjZmYzEzN2UxOThlOGM0ZDRlYg==
```

Vala gives me the following result:

```
ZmRjODM1ODQwNDNmOTM5ODAzY2Q5MzJhMjE4NzQyYmQ2YmRkOWQ1
```

I don't think it is anything to do with encoding of strings as C# and Vala both use the same default encoding. I assumed it was something to do with a null byte at the end of the Data array but, I have checked and there is not a one.

Any advice would be great

**Edit**

Finally got the output in vala to match that of PHP and C#. I forgot to append the GUID but, this doesn't explain why I am getting this in Chrome

```
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to write all this yourself instead of just using the websocket support built into libsoup?  https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/libsoup-2.4-WebSockets.html

Comment: I didn't even know that Libsoup had websocket support. The whole way this started is that I wanted to adjust the server to support websockets. The server was already functioning with it's other clients. I'll see if I can easily drop libsoup in there.

Comment: You should also post your edit as an answer and accept it, just to keep SO clean.

Comment: I am trying out Libsoup first to see if works for me. The amount of files in this project it will take a wee bit of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem was that the SHA1 output I was using was the escaped HEX string rather than the raw binary output.

```
Checksum cs = new Checksum(ChecksumType.SHA1);
cs.update(_base.data, -1);
cs.update("258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11".data, -1);

size_t len = 20;
uint8[] digest = new uint8[len];
cs.get_digest(digest, ref len);
string key = Base64.encode(digest);
```

Found the answer by looking through Libsoup.